# How to restart a frozen NetStream AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, video, netstream, netconnection

I have the following code in my AS3 project:

```
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netConnectionStatus);
netRemoteStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netRemoteStatus);
netRemoteStream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
private function netConnectionStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void 
{
   trace("netStatus = " + event.info.code);
}
private function netRemoteStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void
{
   trace("netRemoteStatus = " + e.info.code);
}
private function asyncErrorHandler(e:AsyncErrorEvent):void
{
   trace("asyncErrorHandler " + e.error);
}
```

I'm subscribed to a NetStream:

```
netRemoteStream = new NetStream(myNetConnection);
netRemoteStream.play("channelToView");
netRemoteStream.bufferTime = 0;
myViewer.attachNetStream(netRemoteStream);
netRemoteStream.receiveAudio(true);
netRemoteStream.receiveVideo(true);
```

But sometimes the video will be frozen and I only receive audio, but not video and the listeners don't show any error. What can i do to solve this? I have to call to "netRemoteStream.play("channelToView");" when the video is frozen, but I don't know when.

For more details, I've used Wireshark sniffer and I have could observed the following traces:
Audio Data
Video data
Set Chunk Size 513
Audio Data

Any idea? Someone can help me?
Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem I guess and no one knows it. Is your problem also restricted to IE? So Chrome and Firefox work properly? My problem occurs always when the publisher stops publishing and starts publishing. The stream of the viewer freezes.